# write a common method for these 3 methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model User which goes like this

```
class User

  ROLES = {
            "Admin" => 1,
            "Manager" => 2,
            "Officer" => 3
          }

  def admin?
    role == 1
  end

  def manager?
    role == 2
  end

  def officer?
    role == 3
  end

end
```

where `role` is a column in `users` table and I was wondering whether I can use a common method to build the 3 role checking methods from the `ROLES` hash?

**Edit**

so this seems to be the answer

```
class User

  ROLES = {
            "Admin" => 1,
            "Manager" => 2,
            "Officer" => 3
          }

  # methods used to identify whether a user is a specific role
  ROLES.each { |k, v| define_method("#{k.downcase}?") { role == v } }

end
```

Comment: `ROLES` is not used in any useful way in your code. How do you want it to be involved?

Comment: def role? current_user.role end ?

Comment: @sawa..`ROLES` basically act as a virtual table `roles`. I am using it in the views to find the role from the value of column `role`(1, 2 or 3) and also populating the drop down for role in add/edit view. Here I want it to map the name of the method to the value of the role(1, 2, 3).

Comment: @mikhail..I am using those methods to check whether a user is admin, manager or officer

Comment: @mikhail `def role? current_user.role end` breaks ruby convention by returning a number or string instead of a boolean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not fully sure of your intention, but maybe like this?

```
class User
  %w[admin manager officer].each_with_index{|m, i| define_method("#{m}?"){role == i+1}}
end
```

or, using `ROLES`,

```
class User
  ROLES.each{|m, i| define_method("#{m.downcase}?"){role == i}}
end
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a couple of options I think.

Firstly you could add a method_missing implementation to check whether the method is one of your role names. Something like:

```
def method_missing?(sym, *args)
  if args.empty? && ROLES.any? { |r| r.downcase + "?" == sym.to_s }
    # No additional arguments and the symbol for the method called 
    # matches a role name
    role == ROLES[sym.to_s.chomp('?')] # Check the value
  else
    super
  end
end
```

Alternatively you could set up methods from your roles hash:

```
class User
  ROLES = { ... }
  ROLES.each_pair do |r, n|
    class_eval "def #{r.downcase}?; role == #{n}; end"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably a few different ways you could do it, the question is, how do you want it to behave, and where do you want your ease of use/flexibility?

If I grasp what you are trying to do, something like this might help

```
def to_methods(roles_hash)
  roles_hash.each_pair do |key, value|
    class_eval {
      "def #{key}?
         role == #{value}
       end" 
    }
  end
end
```

This will create methods for you for each role. Is that what you were looking to do?

Comment: this is exactly what I want..I basically could add more roles to the roles hash and the method will be auto generated.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could do something like this but I think your way reads better...

```
  (ROLES = {
    "Admin"   => 1,
    "Manager" => 2,
    "Officer" => 3,
  }).each { |k, v| define_method(k.downcase + '?') { role == v }}
```